# TypeORM converts javascript date to iso format for timestamp with timezone

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typeorm

I am saving a javascript date object:

```
test.appointmentDateTime = momentz.tz('2021-09-03 10:00:55.006', 'America/Toronto').toDate()
```

into postgres using typeorm.

and the typeORM entity of the test object is declared as below:

```
  @Column({
    type: 'timestamp with time zone',
    name: 'appointment_date_time',
    nullable: true,
  })
  appointmentDateTime: Date | null;
```

But when typeORM saves into my postgres database (I simply call typeORM `repository.save`). Then `appointment_date_time` becomes `2021-09-03 14:00:55.006+00`. Since UTC is 4 hours ahead of 'America/Toronto'. It looks like TypeORM automatically converts `appointment_date_time` to UTC and saves it as a `timestamp with time zone` type. Is there a way to save it without converting it as UTC? Such that it would be saved as `2021-09-03 10:00:55.006+04` (or `2021-09-03 10:00:55.006-04`, can't remember if it is positive or negative)?

The timezone of my postgres is `UTC`. When I run in psql the command `show timezone;`. It is displaying as `UTC`. (Thanks to @Adrian Klaver for this info)

Comment: A `timestamp with time zone` field will store values in UTC. The fact that you are seeing it in the database in UTC indicates to me the database `TimeZone` is set to UTC. In `psql` run `show timezone;` to confirm. Add that information to your question.

Comment: You can't save the time zone offset in the timestamp(tz) field. I would suggest taking a look at docs here [Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT), in particular section 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps.